# pthread void pointer casting

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, void

I am working on an assignment which requires me to use threads to process and synchronize fetching data from a file. My professor told me that I can change my data to a void pointer to pass it to my function and then cast it back. I am trying to do this with file IO.

```
pthread_create(&th1, NULL, processing, (void *)&fp);
```

In my processing function I am trying to cast it back to a FILE pointer with this:

```
FILE driveOne = (FILE *)file;
```

This clearly doesn't work, so can someone explain this to me?

Comment: 1) Casting a `(void *)` to `(FILE *)` should work.  2) Are you sure you want `&fp`, and not `(void *)fp` instead?  3) ALSO: it should be `FILE *driveOne = (FILE *)file`.

Comment: you shouldn't even need to cast `fp` in the call to `pthread_create` if you declared it like this: `FILE *fp;`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more complete example.

Let's say your worker function needs a file handle. For simplicity, let's say it reads each char from it, and returns the number of chars read, cast to a pointer:

```
void *worker(void *data)
{
    FILE      *handle = (FILE *)data;
    uintptr_t  count = 0;

    if (handle && !ferror(handle)) {
        /* handle is a valid file handle */

        while (getc(handle) != EOF)
            count++;
    }

    return (void *)count;
}
```

If `count` were of some other type than `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` (declared in `<stdint.h>`, which is typically included by including `<inttypes.h>`), you'd need to cast it first to that type, and then to void pointer, i.e. `(void *)(uintptr_t)count`.

Because such worker threads don't need much stack (almost none, to be precise), and default thread stack sizes are huge (megabytes), we can save some memory (and allow much more threads if needed, especially on 32-bit architectures) by creating a pthread attribute that instructs `pthread_create()` to use a smaller stack.  This attribute is not "consumed" by the call; it is more like an configuration block.

Let's say you have three streams, `FILE *in[3];`, and you wish to use three threads to check their lengths. Using a pthread attribute to use a smaller stack (`2*PTHREAD_STACK_MIN`, as defined in `<limits.h>`, is a good, safe value for worker threads that don't use `alloca()` or local arrays.):

```
pthread_t       worker_id[3];
uintptr_t       length[3];
pthread_attr_t  attrs;
void           *retptr;
int             i, result;

/* Create a pthread attribute set, defining smaller stack size. */
pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, 2*PTHREAD_STACK_MIN);

/* Create the three worker threads. */
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    result = pthread_create(&(worker_id[i]), &attrs, worker, (void *)in[i]);
    if (result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create thread: %s.\n", strerror(result));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

/* pthread attributes are no longer needed. */
pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);

/*
  ... This thread can do something else here ...
*/

/* Reap the threads, and collect their return values. */
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    result = pthread_join(worker_id[i], &retptr);
    if (result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot reap thread: %s.\n", strerror(result));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    length[i] = (uintptr_t)retptr;
}

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    printf("in[%d] contained %llu chars.\n", i, (unsigned long long)length[i]);
```

---

The same pattern can be used when you want to pass multiple parameters to the thread function. You first construct a structure to hold those parameters, and create them. You can allocate them dynamically, declare them as global variables, or declare them as local variables in main() -- any scope that exists for the full duration when the worker thread exists, works.

For example, let's say your worker function calculates a histogram of each `unsigned char` value it reads from the stream:

```
struct work {
    pthread_t     id;                   /* Thread identifier */
    FILE         *in;                   /* File handle to read from */
    size_t        count[UCHAR_MAX + 1]; /* Histogram */
};

void *worker(void *data) {
    struct work *const  work = (struct worker_data *)data;
    int                 c;

    if (!work || !work->in) {
        /* Invalid data, or invalid file handle. */
        return (void *)(intptr_t)(EINVAL);
    }
    if (ferror(work->in)) {
        /* Stream is in error state. */
        return (void *)(intptr_t)(EIO);
    }

    /* Read the stream. */
    while ((c = getc(work->in)) != EOF) {
        /* Update histogram. */
        work->count[(unsigned char)c]++;
    }

    /* Did the reading stop due to an I/O error? */
    if (ferror(work->in))
        return (void *)(intptr_t)(EIO);

    /* No errors, all done. */
    return (void *)0;
}
```

Note that `struct work *const work = ...` initializes a constant pointer `work`, not a pointer to constant. The `const` there is just an optimization that tells the C compiler that we won't try to modify `work` pointer itself. The data it points to, is modifiable.

(To read pointer declarations, read them from right to left, replacing each `*` with *"is a pointer to"*, to get the proper sense of it.)

The code to create these workers is very similar, except that we allocate the work dynamically:

```
struct work    *work[3];
pthread_attr_t  attrs;
void           *retptr;
int             i, result;

/* Create and initialize the three pointers. */
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    /* Allocate a work structure. */
    work[i] = malloc(sizeof *(work[i]));
    if (!work[i]) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Copy the handle to read from, */
    work[i]->in = in[i];

    /* and clear the histogram part. */
    memset(work[i]->count, 0, sizeof work[i]->count);
}

/* Create a pthread attribute set, defining smaller stack size. */
pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, 2*PTHREAD_STACK_MIN);

/* Create the three worker threads. */
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    result = pthread_create(&(work[i]->id), &attrs, worker, (void *)work[i]);
    if (result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create thread: %s.\n", strerror(result));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

/* pthread attributes are no longer needed. */
pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);

/*
  ... This thread can do something else here ...
*/

/* Reap the threads, and collect their return values. */
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    result = pthread_join(work[i]->id, &retptr);
    if (result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot reap thread: %s.\n", strerror(result));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* If the thread reported a failure, print the corresponding
       error message (but do not exit). */
    if (retptr)
        fprintf(stderr, "Thread %d of 3: %s.\n", i+1, strerror((intptr_t)retptr));

    /* ... print the histogram here? ... */
}

/* Free the work structures. */
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    free(work[i]);
```

If you don't want to abort the program when an error occurs, it is useful to note that `free(NULL)` is safe and does nothing; and that `struct work *pointerarray[SIZE] = {0};` declares an array of SIZE pointers to `struct work`, and initializes them all to zero. For example, if an allocation or thread creation fails at some point, you can just `free()` each pointer, whether or not its allocation was successful.

That is, if you want to allocate three different types of structures (`struct atype *a;`, `struct btype *b;`, and `struct ctype *c;`), you can do

```
a = malloc(sizeof *a);
b = malloc(sizeof *b);
c = malloc(sizeof *c);
if (!a || !b || !c) {
    free(c);
    free(b);
    free(a);
    return ALLOCATION_FAILED;
}

/* Allocation was successful */
```

instead of allocating each one and testing for failure separately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `driveOne` to be `FILE *`, not `FILE`.

```
FILE *driveOne = (FILE *)file;
```

In addition, assuming that `fp` was initially declared as `FILE *`, your call to `pthread_create` should not have & before fp, like so:

```
pthread_create(&th1, NULL, processing, (void *)fp);
```

Comment: Declaring `FILE fp` is **always** wrong. You can't meaningfully create objects of type `FILE`; in C11 and later it's not even necessarily a complete type.

Comment: The cast on `fp` in the `pthread_create()` is not crucial; the prototype for the function essentially does that automatically.  Ditto, the cast in the thread function isn't strictly necessary; C converts from `void *` to other object pointer types automatically (unlike C++).